# GroupsApp.getGroups gives a different number of groups than admin console

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, google-groups

I have a small problem within the GroupsApp.getGroups method.
The call gives me back 37 groups, where the admin console tells me that I'm a member in 43 groups.
The groups that I'm missing, are groups where I'm a direct member.

Anybody else recognizes this problem?

```
function myFunction() {
  var groups = GroupsApp.getGroups();

  for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
    var tempString = groups[i].getEmail();

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

G Suite administrator could create groups that are outside of the Google Groups app. As they are outside of Google Groups they can't be accessed by using GroupsApp.

From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/groups/groups-app

> **Class GroupsApp**
>
> This class provides access to Google Groups
>   information. It can be used to query information such as a group's
>   email address, or the list of groups in which the user is a direct
>   member

On Google Apps Script the alternative is to use the [advanced service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) AdminDirectory. For an example see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory#list_all_groups